# Git pretty format string equivalent of oneline, including colors

Tags: git

I am trying to recreate the Git format setting of `oneline` as a format string (in order to extend it further).

So for this command

```
git log --format=oneline
```

What is the format string equivalent of `oneline`?
The closest I can get is

```
git log --format="%h %d %s"
```

However, this does not produce any colors. I know I can hard code some of them, like the commit hash. But the %d has dynamic colors, depending on what it shows.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Turn on auto color

```
git log --format="%C(auto) %h %d %s"
```

and the output will look like this

[image]

From the [git log documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

> %C(…): color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option; adding auto, at the beginning will emit color only when colors are enabled for log output (by color.diff, color.ui, or --color, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal). **auto alone (i.e. %C(auto)) will turn on auto coloring on the next placeholders until the color is switched again**.

Comment: I struggled a little bit to find it but the exact command to produce the same output as "git reflog" is: git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty="%C(auto)%h%d %gD: %gs"

Comment: On Windows 10 CMD, for some reason, `%h%d` becomes `https://localhost:8888/d`. If you add a space between them, then there is a space before the coloured text that indicates the position of HEAD.

Comment: @Unknow0059 In Windows environment variable substitution is done using `%VAR_NAME%`. Thus it seems that you have an environment variable `h` that contains the localhost URL you posted. Thus `%h%d` is substituted with `https://localhost:8888/d`.  You can list the environment variables by typing `set` on the command line. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

After times of struggling, I finally decide to use a pretty format like this:

```
lg = "log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cblue%ad%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %h %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'"
```

And the pretty effect looks like this
[image]

And here is how to use it:

**Step 1**
Open your ~/.gitconfig file using your favorite editor like emacs or vim. Add below command under the `[alias]` section.

```
lg = "log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cblue%ad%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %h %s %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'"
```

**Step 2**

Within any of your local git repository, try execute:

```
git lg
```

So you are seeing the beautiful formatted log output now, just as the screenshot shows.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to play with the colors. 
The color that you should use to solve your problem is `auto` that take a different color for each type of reference.

An example :

`%Cred%h %Cgreen%<(10,trunc)%cd %C(auto)%d%Creset%s %C(bold blue)%an`

Answer (score 1):

there is a nice script that does it for you. Add it as alias and you will see a cool printings.

https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/blob/master/.githelpers

alias: `l = "!source ~/.githelpers && pretty_git_log"`

Here you have a sample `.gitconfig` file on how to set the alias + more aliases.